# Converting String to Float -> Processing.org

Tags: java, geolocation, type-conversion, processing, latitude-longitude

I am trying to convert String latitude and longitude coordinates into a float because I am plotting them on a map. I have tried a combination of things and it is just not working correctly. Any help would be truly appreciated!

This is my String:

```
String r = loc[1].substring(0, loc[1].length()-1);
It prints out as: 42.202344 (example)

float lon = float(r.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" ));
float lon = Float.valueOf(r.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" ).trim().floatValue());

float lon = Float.valueOf(r.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" )).floatValue();
```

All of the values above yield: 4.2202344E7 <-- which is not plottable.

Comment: is there a reason why `float lon = Float.valueOf(r).floatValue();` won't work? Given your string as `"42.202344"` it should get you the value of `42.202344`.

Comment: I am not sure if this your case, but do not forget, that string representation depends on locale too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the static method [Float.parseFloat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29)? It might make the job easier for you:

```
float lon = Float.parseFloat(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `"[^\d\.]"` or you replace "." too.